# Moveit Gazebo Integration for trajectory execution of panda robot

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, ros-kinetic, ros-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to view the trajectory generated by moveit in gazebo.

I have done motion planning using moveit c++ interface and i'm observing the robot movement in Rviz.
The code moveit c++ interface is [here](https://github.com/mvish7/panda_gazebo_moveit/blob/master/panda_gazebo_config/src/panda_move_group.cpp).

Here are the [controllers](https://github.com/mvish7/panda_gazebo_moveit/blob/master/panda_control/config/panda_control.yaml)from gazebo side

Here are the [controllers](https://github.com/mvish7/panda_gazebo_moveit/blob/master/panda_gazebo_config/panda_gazebo_config/config/controllers.yaml) from moveit side

controller manager file is [here](https://github.com/mvish7/panda_gazebo_moveit/blob/master/panda_gazebo_config/panda_gazebo_config/launch/panda_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml)

My questions are as follows[answered below]:-

1. What kind of controllers are necessary to observe the trajectory generated by moveit in gazebo?  Can anybody give some example??
2. I know that moveit c++ interface communicates with Rviz by using some ROS topics/ Actions?
   How can i find over which topic/action moveit c++ interface communicates with rviz so that i can use it same ROS topic/action to communicate with Gazebo.

Updated questions:

1. When i launch [moveit_planning_execution file](https://github.com/mvish7/panda_gazebo_moveit/blob/master/panda_gazebo_config/panda_gazebo_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution_gazebo.launch) i get the error saying **Action client not connected: /joint_trajectory_action**

Below is the snapshot of the error[image: image description]

can anybody help in this??
Any kind of help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309718/moveit-gazebo-integration-for-trajectory-execution-of-panda-robot/) by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working through this recently.  I am not working with the panda robot, so I can't point you to code for the panda. However, I have been using the [ABB 120](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_experimental/tree/kinetic-devel/abb_irb120_gazebo) repository as an example.  There are a lot of layers to work through, but all the information is there.

To do my best to answer your questions directly:

1. You will likely need the joint_state_controller/JointStateController and the position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController, see the above ABB repo for examples.
2. As a starting point, you don't really need to be aware of specific topics, you can use the MoveGroupInterface (which I see you are using in your code).

---

Originally posted by [ryan.delgizzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/38782/ryan.delgizzi/) with karma: 86 on 2018-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2018-12-01**:
Thank you for answering.
I'll try out your suggestions and post my findings here.

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2018-12-02**:
@ryan.delgizzi: I have adapted my files as per the reference. Gazebo and controllers are getting launched correctly but when i launch moveit i get error saying "Action client not connected:joint_trajectory_action"

i have not got any cluw how to solve this can you offer some help?

**Comment by [ryan.delgizzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/38782/ryan.delgizzi/) on 2018-12-10**:
The /joint_trajectory_action is how the move_group communicates with gazebo.  I believe that gets launched from whatever you analogous file is to [this one](https://github.com/rosindustrial/abb_experimental/blob/kinetic-devel/abb_irb120_gazebo/launch/irb120_3_58_control.launch)